# onEditingComplete not working when there is a click on the check mark in the bottom right of keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is the code:

```
TextField(
                                            controller: _textEditingController,
                                            cursorColor: Colors.white70,
                                            autofocus: true,
                                            textCapitalization:
                                                TextCapitalization.sentences,
                                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                              fillColor: Color(0xFF616161),
                                              filled: true,
                                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                                25,
                                              ),
                                              border: InputBorder.none,
                                              hintText:
                                                  'Enter a title to remember your scan',
                                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white70,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                            onEditingComplete: () {
                                              print('yes');
                                            },
                                          ),
```

the print statement passed to the onEditingComplete parameter's function doesn't execute when tapped on the check mark in the keyboard placed in the bottom right. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: works perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided us with works perfectly fine, if there's a problem it might be something else overriding it or simply a bug, try flutter clean, and restarting the whole app instead of hot-reload.

Anyway I assume you want to pass the written text into a variable when the user is done editing. For that it's better to use onChanged. this will save the text every time its changed, which makes it a lot easier for the user, pretty much nobody uses the finish button on the keyboard these days, they just hop from textfield to textfield.

```
onChanged: (value) {
             setState(() {
                inputText = value;
             });
            },
```